# How to append within a string variable in a looping?

Tags: python, string, interaction

I have the list position:

```
position = ["North", "Center", "South"]
```

I want to append values that I read from an xlsx file in a looping, So I would have North1 as the column B from one excel file, Center1 from another excel file and so on. This is what I have done so far:

```
for p in position:

    for i in sheets_heights:
        sheetHeights = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(path,filename), data_only=True)
        heights = sheetHeights.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

        North1=[]
        North2=[]
        North3=[] #here I wanted to create North1, Center1, South1 as a looping...
        North4=[]

#here I wanted to get the variables created on the looping above and append the column values from excel

    for row in range (2, heights.max_row+1):
        Time.append(heights['A' + str(row)].value)
        p.__add__North1.append(heights['B' + str(row)].value) #test
        North2.append(heights['C' + str(row)].value)
        North3.append(heights['D' + str(row)].value)
        North4.append(heights['E' + str(row)].value)
```

How do I make the last part to be inside the looping?

Comment: could you elaborate your question?Which last part?

Comment: is it better now? I was referring to the last looping

Comment: You probably don't want the stray `p.__add__` there either?

Comment: no, it was just a test

Answer (score 0):

Indent the second loop 4 more spaces, and that will put it inside the "for i in sheets_heights" loop.

Edit: The resulting code is:

```
North1=[]
North2=[]
North3=[] #here I wanted to create North1, Center1, South1 as a looping...
North4=[]

for p in position:

    for i in sheets_heights:
        sheetHeights = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(path,filename), data_only=True)
        heights = sheetHeights.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

        #here I wanted to get the variables created on the looping above and append the column values from excel

        for row in range (2, heights.max_row+1):
            Time.append(heights['A' + str(row)].value)
            North1.append(heights['B' + str(row)].value)
            North2.append(heights['C' + str(row)].value)
            North3.append(heights['D' + str(row)].value)
            North4.append(heights['E' + str(row)].value)
```

Comment: but that doesn't solve my problem. I am probably miswriting something

Comment: The code modified by me will still reset the Northx arrayy for each sheet. You should probbaly move those 4 initialisation lines to before the "for p in position:". I'll add the exact modified code to my answer.